# jQuery change variable on click?

Tags: jquery, variables, click

i am sure its a simple thing. But i cant find the solution. My Code:

```
var lang='de';

$('#en').click(function (){
    lang='en';
});
```

The variable dont change / updates on click, why?

Thanks!

Solution: works not local only on Webserver for me.

Comment: Needs more info and code. Does `#en` exist at all?

Comment: the js is loaded after the html of before?

Comment: Ok it was simple, my code works at all but not local only on webserver it change de to en variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to work fine for me.
More than likely you have a scope issue.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su3RC/1/)

Comment: If you put alert(lang); outside $, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does.  Here is the jsFiddle test -

http://jsfiddle.net/RfDCU/

With your Html revision it works too -

http://jsfiddle.net/RfDCU/1/

Are you sure the lang variable is within function scope?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the `document.ready` ?

```
$(function(){
var lang='de';
    $('#en').click(function (){
        lang='en';
    });
});
```