# Through jQuery get the image clicked src and put in another image src

Tags: jquery

I need to get the source src URL from image clicked as HTML below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    var var1 = $(this).find('.thumbnail img').attr('src');
    console.log(var1);
    $('#main_image').attr('src', var1).load(function() {});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thumbnail">
<img src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/agv_0041A2HY-002_b.jpg" width="200">
<img src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/agv_0041A2HY-006_b.jpg" width="200">
<span>

<br /><br /><br />
Put inside this 
<img id="main_image" src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/added-desc/agv_0041A2HY-02211_415x500.jpg" width="400">
```

I tried the jQuery code as you see posted.

For some reason it throws `undefined`.

Here is in action http://jsfiddle.net/1oaxue9h

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506317/jquery-change-variable-on-click
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784144/change-img-src-on-click

These two posts might help

Comment: @Alyss Both the posts won't help him. It's because of the wrong selector used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, even when the <kbd>Tidy</kbd> button is provided, people are lazy to tidy their codes.

[Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/). You need to remove the `.thumbnail` from the selector to work. Coz, you are already here, which is denoted by `this`. Since, `this` is `.thumbnail`, just `find("img")` is enough.

```
var var1 = $(this).attr('src');
```

You also have an unclosed `<span>`, which needs to be changed as `</span>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbnail img").click(function() {
    var var1 = $(this).attr('src');
    console.log(var1);
    $('#main_image').attr('src', var1).load(function() {});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/agv_0041A2HY-002_b.jpg" width="200">
  <img src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/agv_0041A2HY-006_b.jpg" width="200">
</span>

<br /><br /><br />
Put inside this 
<img id="main_image" src="http://www.euroe-com.com/agv/graphics/added-desc/agv_0041A2HY-02211_415x500.jpg" width="400">
```

Comment: hi Praveen, you are right, one thing though, if you test the modified code you provided, when is clicked on the Red image, still appears the black one. Please see it once more from your side. Thank You a lot

Comment: @Mistereri Try once more... I changed. Refresh the page.

Comment: you are great man. It was so simple and neat solution. I lost a full day to find it by my self so I gave up and wrote it here. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I did it Praveen, sorry it was my first time i have posted here. happy holidays.